# navigation icon and back button not showing up in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework

Nav Icon and Back button does not show up, If I use header bar instead of nav bar the icon shows up only in the first page.

```
  <ion-pane ion-side-menu-content>

    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-balanced">
```

ion-nav-back-button breaks my whole code here without any console errors

```
<button class="button-clear button-icon icon ion-arrow-left-a"></button>

</ion-nav-bar>
<ion-nav-view name="mainContent" animation="slide-left-right"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-pane>
```

can anyone help me with this fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give color with css.

```
  <ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-yeni">
      <ion-nav-back-button style="color: white !important">
      </ion-nav-back-button>
      ...
```

Comment: It was a color issue. Thanks.